# Help explaining how signal is measured with no ground reference

Tags: ground, logic-analyzer

The picture shows a car LED module that is controlled with a pulsed +12 V to change its brightness. I want to measure the range of this PWM using a cheap logic analyzer that I have but it can only handle voltages up to 5 V.
So I connected my analyzer to the points I marked A & B (on the picture) but got nothing. However, when I connected my analyzer to just point A with no ground it started reading the pulses! (not sure how accurate these readings are)

The logic analyzer is connected to a laptop that is running off its batteries, so no common ground with the car's ground.

I assume using B as ground is not correct since it is almost similar to (A - LED drop voltage) and both are changing with the same pulse, and that will not trigger a logic change.
I cannot use the car ground, since with only 300 ohm resistor I am afraid the value will be more than 5 V and damage my analyzer.

So here are my questions:

1. How can I measure the data without burning my analyzer?
2. How did I get a reading on the analyzer when it doesn't have a common ground with the other circuit? Won't that make it like an open circuit?
3. Why did they put two resistors one before and the other after the LED? Is there any advantages to that instead of just putting both on one side? Especially since there is a lot of empty space in this module.

[image]

Comment: A simple voltage divider?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I measure the data without burning my analyzer?

Because, as you wrote:

> The logic analyzer is connected to a laptop that is running off its batteries, so no common ground with the car's ground

There are only **two** direct connections between your measurement device and the car. The car has its own ground. Your measurement setup has its own ground. That those two grounds are connected **at one point** is OK, no current can flow. More problemetic would be if you made **two** connections (like what you did + shorting analyzer ground and car ground) then that could result in a loop where a large current could flow. By having only one connection, that large current cannot flow.

> How did I get a reading on the analyzer when it doesn't have a common ground with the other circuit?

"Ground" is just a **reference point** for us humans to refer to. Circuits actually don't care about ground or common. To a circuit, it is just a connection point in the circuit.

> However, when I connected my analyzer to just point A with no ground it started reading the pulses!

I bet that the analyzer's input is very high impedance (1 Mohm or so). Then there only needs to be a **weak** connection to "close the loop" so that a minute current can flow and a voltage can be measured. There doesn't even have to be a connection, this can also work only on **capacitance**. If your laptop is resting on a metal part of the car then that could be enough.

You will not measure in an accurate way like this, it is more reliable to have two proper connections like in my schematics below.

Your analyzer only needs to see a voltage at its input. That the car's circuit has a different ground than your analyzer + laptop doesn't matter since those grounds are not connected.

I show here two schematics that you could use, on the left the grounds are **not** connected. As an LED will usually have a forward voltage of less than 4 V, you can just directly measure across the LED.

The circuit on the right shows how you can safely measure across the inputs using a voltage divider. Note how the grounds **are** shorted but that is not a must, if the PWM switch was in the ground line the grounds would not be shorted but this circuit would still work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXn7r4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Won't that make it like an open circuit?

No because you still measure across a resistor with **two** connections.

> Why did they put two resistors one before and the other after the LED?

This is likely to divide the **power dissipation** between the two resistors. They could have used only **one** resistor but then it would have to be larger and more expensive. Also dividing the power across multiple resistors is more reliable as more resistors allow for spreading the heat across a larger area.

Also note how one resistor has a large area A to dissipate heat (the copper on the PCB acts as a heatsink) while the other resistor has a large area B to get rid of its heat.

Comment: I understood the question that there is no other connection than logic analyzer data wire going to point A. Meaning the laptop "common" and car "common" were not connected at all.

Comment: @Justme Sure that could be the case then the ground connection could be "weak" and/or "capacitive". It could still work but with a lot of noise etc. Same as with an oscilloscope input where you forget to connect the ground. I'll include this in my answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie My first setup was the same as your left schematic but the analyzer was reading nothing (pulled high as open circuit), however, when I disconnected (and it was done by mistake) the second connection (which you labeled as analyzer GND) the analyzer started showing pulses!

Comment: Like what @Justme is clarifying, the only connection is the data wire and the laptop was setting on my lap, so there is no other types of connections with the car.